# How to retrieve records for last 30 minutes in MS SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to retrieve records for last 30 minutes in a table. How to do that? Below is my query..

```
select * from
[Janus999DB].[dbo].[tblCustomerPlay]
where DatePlayed < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
and DatePlayed >
(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-30)
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Change this `(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-30)`

To This:  `DateADD(mi, -30, Current_TimeStamp)`

To get the current date use GetDate().

[MSDN Link to DateAdd Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)
[MSDN Link to Get Date Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx)

Answer (score 58):

Have a look at using [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

something like

```
SELECT DATEADD(minute, -30, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 10):

Use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Janus999DB].[dbo].[tblCustomerPlay] 
WHERE DatePlayed <  GetDate() 
AND DatePlayed > dateadd(minute, -30, GetDate())
```

Answer (score 3):

`DATEADD` only returned `Function does not exist` on MySQL 5.5.53 (I know it's old)

Instead, I found `DatePlayed > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 30 minute)` to produce the desired result

Comment: Question was for MS SQL not MySQL.. Makes this a confusing answer for me.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - (number) works fine, but that you need to understand what number it is looking for - it is floating-point number of days. So CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-1.0 is 1 day ago, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-0.5 is 1/2 day ago. For 30 minutes, that is 1.0/48.0 (use radix so result is a floating point number) or 0.0208333333333333, so your query will work if re-written as

```
select * from
[Janus999DB].[dbo].[tblCustomerPlay]
where DatePlayed < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
and DatePlayed >
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP-1.0/48.0
```

You could also use 1.0/24.0/2.0 if that looks more like 1/2 hour to you.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server uses Julian dates so your 30 means "30 calendar days".  getdate() - 0.02083 means "30 minutes ago".