# Using SQL SELECT, how do I display records with set time apart from each other

Tags: c#, sql-server, reportviewer

I'm currently busy building a small application that monitors a bunch of tables.

Each table contains temperature values punched in by a PLC.

The PLC sends the data every minute.

The client however wished to draw reports for that day or week on a trend table and still display a table below the graph with the values depicted in the graph.

So the challenge comes in that if you look at a day (1440) and even worse a week (10080) the report table will become too long and plotting this on a trend table the width of an A4/Letter page (even in landscape) is just stupid to say the least. And the client knows this, so he asked if I can plot the values for every half an hour.

This leaves me to my question; How do I do a SELECT statement to show me only values for every 30min?

Example Table has the following fields:

```
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_SAPO_T3_Date]  DEFAULT (getdate()),
[Air1] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Email] [varchar](100) NULL,
[Number] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
[InAlarm] [bit] NULL,
```

Any help would be great.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve records for last 30 minutes in MS SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471041/how-to-retrieve-records-for-last-30-minutes-in-ms-sql)

Comment: 'Sample Data' and 'Expected Result' would help us a lot

Comment: No? We have the structure of his table which is all we need to give an answer. @Mark

Comment: so is the logic you're looking for something like select * from table where [minute part of date mod 30 = 0]?

Comment: Not exactly the same as "How to retrieve records for last 30 min" @The PerplexedOne

Comment: Do you want to group the values by each 30 minutes or only want to retrieve the data for a certain time?

Comment: Yes it is. The answer in that topic will give you records **from 30 minutes ago to now**. @stephenmh83

Comment: @simonalexander2005 in plain English I would say the select statement would read: SELECT * FROM Table WHERE [DateTimeColumn]  Is not every minute, but every 30min

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne Sample Data and Expected Result will make a better understanding about the question itself. For me, this question is not clear. Whether he just want to take the last 30 minutes data, then he will repeat taking the data in the next 30 minutes, or he wants to take the data once and group by all the data for every 30 minutes.

Comment: if you need every 30 minutes grouped, then you can extract hour, and minute and do a case statement to do 0-29 as 0 and 30-59 as 30, and then you have your groupped minutes...

Comment: I don't only want 30min ago, I want the whole table between 2 specified dates and all results must be 30min apart instead of 1min apart

Comment: I'm fairly new to stackoverflow and SQL in general. So please excuse my ignorance. Where would I post the sample data? In the comments or by using the answer my question button?

Comment: edit your question to do so :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM tableName      
  WHERE DATEPART(MI,[DATE]) % 30 = 0
     AND [DATE] < maxDate AND [DATE] > minDate
```

The above sql will select every entry where the minute is 0 or 30 (or any other multiple of 30), which assuming you really are polling every minute, should satisfy what you need. It doesn't aggregate the data inbetween though, so if you want an average for each of the 30 minute intervals, you'll need a different piece of SQL.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? I think it matches the specification - "I don't only want 30min ago, I want the whole table between 2 specified dates and all results must be 30min apart instead of 1min apart "

Comment: you're welcome :) like I say, it's not an average over each 30 minute period, so it may not be completely representative of the data - depends on what your requirements are really. If it helped, feel free to upvote it or mark it as the answer (green tick)

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but if I was with the questioner now, my first question would be whether or not he wanted the average temperature over the half hour, otherwise why not just set the machine to sample half hourly - it seems to be 'downvote' week to me though, with downvoting of  all sorts of spurious stuff

Comment: Looking at the answer, I now see I was wrong in the "downvote". I looked into my eye-lids on that one. Thanks to all for quick responses and willingness to help

Comment: no problem :) you can undo it by clicking it again, if you think it wasn't justified. Welcome to StackOverflow, by the way :)

Comment: if he doesn't want that though, great!

Comment: I didn't actually do a downvote, thought you were referring to me disregarding the suggested page by @ThePerplexedOne
It would've worked If I just opened my eyes. And thanks for the welcome, sure there will be many more questions.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is calculate the average over each 30 minute period

```
    DECLARE @StartTime AS DATETIME = '20160101';
    DECLARE @EndTime AS DATETIME = '20160108';

    WITH SLOTS AS (SELECT @STARTTIME AS T 
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT DATEADD(n,30,T) FROM SLOTS WHERE DATEADD(n,30,T) < @EndTime)

        select S.T, COALESCE(AVG(Y.AIR1),0) AS Av_Temp  from slots S LEFT join YourTable Y ON S.T <= Y.[Date] AND Y.Date < DATEADD(n,30,S.T)
        GROUP BY S.T
```

tweaked it to allow for slots with no readings, possibly - maybe they should say N/A or not be there

Comment: I think this is a more comprehensive answer than mine - it's certainly what I'd want in the OP's situation